# Mobx - how track deep changes with dynamic form inputs?

Tags: typescript, mobx, mobx-react

i need it on forms.
My form is like this in data submit:

```
const initial = {
    name "",
    surname: "",
    adresses: new Array()  <- this give me  warning when array empty *
}
```

my adresses is array of objects in which i have got some standard properties and i can add new one property, using extendObservable
adresses type of {state:'',town:'' }

```
extendObservable(this.props.data['adresses'][i], { [keyName]: '' });
```

my problem is that doing extendObservable to add new property to adresses i do not see (observe) any change in live, but if, after doing extendObservable, i update the value of state i can see the new added property. Why i do not see the new property the time i added it to adresses?

my store is this (typescript):

```
const initial = {
   namel: "",
    surname: "",
    addresses: new Array()
}

export class formStore {
    constructor() {
        this.formData = initial
    }
    @observable formData: {
        [index: string]: any,
        name: string,
        surname: string,
        addresses: any[]
    };
    @action updatePropertyForm(key: string, value: any) {
        this.formData[key] = value;
    }

    @action updatePropertyAddresses(key: string, value: string, i: number) {
        this.formData.addresses[i][key] = value;
    }

    @action initializeFormData(data: any) {
        this.formData = data;
    }

     @action addEmptyAddress() {
        const emptyAddress = {
            state: "",
            townl: "",
        }
        this.formData['addresses'].push(emptyAddress);
    }

    @action addPropertyToAddresses(_keyName: string) {
        const length = this.formData['addresses'].length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            let keyName = _keyName
            keyName = keyName.replace(/\s/g, '')
            keyName = toLowerChar(keyName);
            extendObservable(this.formData['addresses'][i], { [keyName]: '' });
        }
    }    

    @action removePropetyFromAddresses(_keyName: string) {
        const length = this.formData['addresses'].length;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                let keyName = _keyName
                delete this.formData['addresses'][i][keyName];
            }
    }
}
```

by calling add or remove i have to update one of other properties so can i see the new property i added. 
How observe it when i put new property?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the problem. Do you mind to reformulate `my problem is that this to work i have to trigger for once one of property in adresses[i] by changing value then the input new appear which is observable. How make it appear instantly when i add new property to adresses?` with shorter phrases please?

Comment: I tried to reformulate it, i hope you understand.

Comment: `i update the value of state` where do you do that? Note that a property added with extendObservable won't trigger any observer because only properties which are present at the observer initialisation will be actually observed. Does it help?

Comment: Rereading your problem, one solution could be to use a mobx.map which trigger observers when adding/removing an item (or a prop in your case)

Comment: Yeah i saw the map usage for dynamic properties. but how i use it in my store? i tried  addresses: observable.map() but this wrong and do not work. I thought i need something like this   
addresses: Array<observable.map()> <- this is not workable (error).

Comment: Could you past the observer block code?

Comment: I do not think if there is issue, cause i use adresses properties to render inputs. so if address is addresses:[{state:'',town:''}]
i render one input for state and for town, when i update input i call updatePropertyAddresses. This work well. But if i add dynamically propery postalCode sto addresses bcome addresses[{state:'',town:'', postalCode:''}] i do not see this new input for postalCode unless i will update state -> addresses[{state:'test',town:'', postalCode:''}]

Comment: It is normal. You don't see a new input because the observer don't care about new props added to your object. But if you use a map instead it will work. I will try to write a POC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the doc you [can only observe objects properties which exist during observer init](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observable.html).

If you want to observe a dynamically keyed object (as your address object), you have to use the `asMap` modifier (or directly a mobx.map as I did in my exemple)

Like this :

```
// add a first addresse
store.addresses.push(mobx.observable.map({town: "Stormwind", street: "Dwarf lane"}));

// add a props to the first addresse
store.addresses[0].set("number", 2);
```

Here is a working example.

https://jsbin.com/lasudor/2/edit?js,console

Comment: Yes this working like this. I will marked it as answer. But for now i started using typescript with it and found a solution by using arrays of type class that i define.  for example by doing this:
class AddressDefinition {
       constructor(id: string, title:string, value: any) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.value = value;
    };
 \@observable title:string
 \@observable value:any
}

By doing this i have got observable "object" . I am new with typescript thats why it was hard to find this.